# Spring Cloud Gateway : High CPU Utilization on RHEL : Possible to switch from epoll to NIO

Tags: netty, project-reactor, spring-cloud-gateway, reactor-netty

As mentioned in the below issue, we are seeing high cpu utilization in a spring cloud gateway app deployed on RHEL. Details available in below link

https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gateway/issues/1908

As per suggestion given by @spencergibb, have tried with latest versions of gateway and boot but still seeing high cpu utilization during PST. Seems bulk of the utilization is done by reactor "epoll" threads.

Are there any reactor/netty optimizations that can be tried to improve performance? Seems besides "epoll"  there is option of using NIO - is this switch possible?

I can see below warning in the logs. Does this have anything to do with this high cpu utilization -

```
[2020-08-21 13:45:38,537] [] [15854] [main] [DEBUG] [i.n.u.internal.NativeLibraryLoader] - Unable to load the library 'netty_transport_native_epoll_x86_64', trying other loading mechanism.
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no netty_transport_native_epoll_x86_64 in java.library.path

[2020-08-21 13:45:38,567] [] [15884] [main] [DEBUG] [i.n.u.internal.NativeLibraryLoader] - Successfully loaded the library /tmp/libnetty_transport_native_epoll_x86_6488
16793540849624173.so
[2020-08-21 13:45:38,568] [] [15885] [main] [DEBUG] [r.netty.resources.DefaultLoopEpoll] - Default Epoll support : true
[2020-08-21 13:45:38,569] [] [15886] [main] [DEBUG] [r.netty.resources.DefaultLoopKQueue] - Default KQueue support : false
[2020-08-21 13:45:38,581] [] [15898] [main] [DEBUG] [i.n.c.MultithreadEventLoopGroup] - -Dio.netty.eventLoopThreads: 12
```

Answer (score 2):

You can control which transport will be used via system property or via configuration on the server/client level. As you are in Spring Gateway it is better to control it via system property. Use `-Dreactor.netty.native=false`.
[Here](https://projectreactor.io/docs/netty/release/reference/index.html#server-tcp-level-configurations-event-loop-group) you can find more about configuring the threads etc.

For the linked issue for Spring Gateway, try to separate JMeter from Spring Gateway it is not OK to run them on one and the same machine.

Comment: Thanks Violeta. Switch is working as now i am seeing "reactor-http-nio*" in logs instead of "reactor-http-epoll*" but the cpu utilization is worse than before. This time I ran Jmeter from a diff machine. I have tried increasing worker thread count as well but that also did not have any affect. Are there any other optimizations at gateway/reactor/netty/server level I can try?

Comment: Can you disable the logging as an experiment and run the scenario again?

Comment: Yes root logging was at DEBUG. Once that was made ERROR, keeping only access log enabled, utilization did come down. On top of this setting, if we add the filter for request/response body logging, again utilization went up. Response body size used for testing was significantly high. So essentially more the logging or more the size of data being logged, more is the utilization. Is this correct? Any further optimizations can be done around this since we would need some kind of logging to make out what request was having any issue in production. Thanks for your support!

Comment: Also observed that with 500 parallel threads, ramp up time as 10 seconds, delay as 1 second; the utilization shoots up to ~ 200 % at the start of PST and then it starts to come down gradually till it settles around ~ 60-70% for the rest of test.

Comment: I was thinking that it might be related to the fact that you use ch.qos.logback.classic.AsyncAppender only for the access log, the rest is not async. Is that correct? Blocking in non-blocking application is not recommended.

Comment: You know that there is wire logger in spring gateway, don't you? https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/2.1.x/multi/multi_troubleshooting.html#_wiretap

Comment: If we use all appender in below fashion, would it help -<appender name="async" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.AsyncAppender">
         <appender-ref ref="accessLog" />
       </appender>  where "accessLog" is "RollingFileAppender". Yes have tried wiretapping but the logs come in a hex format. I was trying to have one main application log file and another just to capture the request and response. With wiretapping enabled, is it possible to separate out the request/response into a separate log file?

Comment: yes it is the same as with access log, `reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient` and `reactor.netty.http.server.HttpServer` loggers should go to a separate appender.

Comment: I added async appenders in similar fashion to access log for httpclient and httpserver. Both async appenders pointing to same "appender-ref". This logs a lot of information in new log file and also cpu utilization is very high ~ 300 %. Is there any way to selectively log only the request and response body only using wiretap?

Comment: I would recommend to move that discussion to the Spring Gateway issue above